# The server tag is not well formed? what did I do?

Tags: asp.net

I am having an issue with my intranet and I was trying to ID each file by changing little things and see how it reflect on the page (changing colors, size of fonts, etc ) BUT I think I think I went to far or by mistake I type something in the wrong place.

This is the part I am having problems.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Width: 651px">
```

I changed the WIDTH a few times trying to the change on the site but nothing changed so I put it back to 651px, but now I am getting this error on the site.

```
Parser Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
 Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
Source Error: 
Line 3:  </asp:Content>
Line 4:  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
Line 5:  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Line 6:   Width: 651px">
Line 7:  <Columns>
```

LINE 5 IS IN RED.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, your server tag is not well-formed.  It's basically a syntax error because you're missing a quote and using a colon instead of an equals.  Take a look at the other attributes on the tag, then look at yours.  Note the difference:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Width: 651px">
```

should be:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Width="651px">
```

Come to think of it, shouldn't `Width` be an integer?  It might need to be:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Width="651">
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

I know this probably was a stupid question, but man I have not idea what I am doing with this codes. I am actually trying to resolve a bigger issue and in the process of trying to id each file and what it does I screwed this up, but thank you for your help..
Have a great day.